# Djoser Password reset confirmation

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, djoser

I have checked many resources,till now I couldn not understand how to setup password reset confirm.How do I do that?I can send email in /u/admin/register/reset_password/ endpoint but when it directs I don't know the process.It said no password reset confirm url,I set it in djoser settings but I got below error.I would like to know whole password reset process in djoser from start.
[image]
after i click post below error shows up.
[image]

```
my settings.py:
DJOSER = {
    "USER_ID_FIELD": "username",
    "LOGIN_FIELD": "email",
    "PASSWORD_RESET_CONFIRM_URL": "u/admin/register/reset_password_confirm/{uid}/{token}",
    "ACTIVATION_URL": "/activate/{uid}/{token}",
    "SEND_ACTIVATION_EMAIL": True,
    "SERIALIZERS": {},
    'PASSWORD_CHANGED_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION':True
    # "EMAIL": {"password_reset": "users.views.ResetPasswordView"},
}
```

Answer (score 0):

set up your Django email

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'samuelosondu99@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'your-email-password'
```

or print to your console with

EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'